# Using VBA, scraping content of classes within classes in html file

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from the below html code.

More precisely, for each i and j classes "flightCabin3 colmn[i] flightCabinOption_[j] cabin-block" (note: these classes are unique), get the content of the sub-classes "travel-class" and then either the "noAvlbl" class or the content of the "message-number-of-seats" class.

(To either know that there is no availability, like the below example in Premium Economy, or that there are X seats available, like 2 seats in Club World in the below example)

```
<div class="travel-class-detail">
    <div class="flightCabin3 colmn1 flightCabinOption_0 cabin-block">
        <div class="cabin-data">
            <div class="flightOption-size1-0 flight-cabin-detail">
                <span class="travel-class">Premium Economy</span>
                <span class="tick">
                    <!--success tick--></span>
                <div class="div-vertical-center3">
                    <div class="priceSelectionContainer3">
                        <div class="priceSelection1-0">
                            <div class="outerDivRadioCls" id="notAvailableTxt0-0-W">
                                <span class="noAvlbl" id="txtNtAvl0-0-W" aria-label="Cabin World Traveller Plus not available for this flight option">Not Available</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flightCabin3 colmn2 flightCabinOption_0 cabin-block">
        <div class="cabin-data number-of-seats-available">
            <div class="flightOption-size1-0 flight-cabin-detail seats-available">
                <span class="message-number-of-seats">
                    <a data-loading-text="Please wait..." data-show-loading="true" data-body-close="true" data-content-id="main-content" data-modal-class="small-modal ivsg-style seat-avail-modal" data-close-option="both" data-inline-modal="false" class="tertiaryLink modal-link" href="https://www.britishairways.com/travel/redempseatsavail/execclub/_gf/en_gb" aria-label="2 seats left for cabin Club World" title="2 LEFT" data-di-id="di-id-21267319-3fccf49a">2 LEFT</a></span>
                <span class="travel-class">Business Class</span>
                <span class="tick">
                    <!--success tick-->
                </span>
                <div class="div-vertical-center3">
                    <div class="priceSelectionContainer3">
                        <div class="priceSelection1-0">
                            <div class="outerDivRadioCls" id="DtlOuterDivRadio0-0-C">
                                <input type="hidden" id="hdnSlngClsSB0-0-C" name="hdnSlngClsSB0-0-C" value="I">
                                <input data-sector-index="0" class="cabinSelector" id="journey0RadioButton0CabinCodeC" value="BA00015Friday 4 May 2023" name="0" type="radio" aria-label="Select /Enter to select cabin Club World">
                                <input class="shfv0" type="hidden" value="SHFV">
                                <label for="journey0RadioButton0CabinCodeC" class="txtAvlSlctCls hideIt" id="txtAvlSlct0-0-C">Available
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flightCabin3 colmn3 flightCabinOption_0 cabin-block">
        <div class="cabin-data">
            <div class="flightOption-size1-0 flight-cabin-detail">
                <span class="travel-class">First</span>
                <span class="tick">
                    <!--success tick-->
                </span>
                <div class="div-vertical-center3">
                    <div class="priceSelectionContainer3">
                        <div class="priceSelection1-0">
                            <div class="outerDivRadioCls" id="notAvailableTxt0-0-F">
                                <span class="noAvlbl" id="txtNtAvl0-0-F" aria-label="Cabin First not available for this flight option">Not Available</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My understanding of VBA is very basic. I've been able to get the data from other elements on the page using "getElementByID" and innerText, but I'm not sure what to do here given these elements don't have IDs, but classes, which aren't unique. (eg. "Travel class" shows up several time, how can I know which travel class is paired with which availability?)

I've been able to use querySelectorAll to identify the object "flightcabin3 [...]" but I'm not sure how to go from there.

This is what I have done so far

```
Sub Scraper() 

Dim nodeDeparture_Time As Object 
Dim nodeClass As Object 
Dim Departure_Time As String 
Dim Class(2, 3) As String 

Set nodeDeparture_Time = ie.document.getElementByID("dtlDepartureTime0_0_1") 
Departure_Time = nodeDeparture_Time.innerText 

Set nodeClass = ie.document.querySelectorAll("flightCabin3 colmn1 flightCabinOption_0 cabin-block") 

Range("A1").Value = Departure_Time 

End Sub
```

Also for some reason I had to use "querySelectorAll" instead of "getElementbyTagName" which didn't work (despite being on IE9?)

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `GetElementsByTagName` and iterate through the results. Could you post your code or at least explain how it's being run? This is something typically done using [Selenium Basic](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/), but not VBA. Please clarify.

Comment: I'm running this on VBA within excel. Here's one sub of my script (I have other subs to login to the website and launch a search query that gets us to this webpage):

Sub Scraper()

Dim nodeDeparture_Time As Object
Dim nodeClass As Object
Dim Departure_Time As String
Dim Class(2, 3) As String



Set nodeDeparture_Time = ie.document.getElementByID("dtlDepartureTime0_0_1")
Departure_Time = nodeDeparture_Time.innerText


Set nodeClass = ie.document.querySelectorAll("flightCabin3 colmn1 flightCabinOption_0 cabin-block")


Range("A1").Value = Departure_Time


End Sub

Comment: Please edit the question and put the code and additional information there. It's really hard to read in the comments and really needs to be part of the question.

Comment: You can easily hit a dead end working from a rendered web page (as opposed to having direct access to the underlying data). And lack of IDs on elements makes it even harder. The tools at your disposal to access elements without IDs are `GetElementsByTagName`, `GetElementsByClassName`, and `querySelectorAll`. I have some simple examples of using each of those [here](https://github.com/LesFerch/SampleCode/tree/main/HTA-ChangeTheme).

Comment: Thank you, I edited my original post with the code I'm currently running. Is there any way to have access to the underlying data, rather than the rendered page? When I launch a search, I have to fill in specific inputs in a form, that then loads a page with all the content pre-loaded on it (part of the html code, not a JSON file)

Comment: You need more knowlege of the basics. At first you should understand how the get methods work. You can find a lot of information about web scraping, here on SO. For a first explanation read the answer behind the following link. Especially the part `Excursus for some get-methods of the DOM (Document Object Model):` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302348/scraping-table-behind-login-wall/75315052#75315052

Comment: In your question, you have "getElementbyTagName" (singular). It should be "getElementsbyTagName" (plural). Maybe that's why it didn't work?

Comment: For direct access to the data, Internet search **flight data api**, though I have some doubt about getting a particular airline's seat information. In general, data access APIs range from free to very expensive paid subscriptions. You'll have to research and see what's available for your application.